# Java Servlet in Eclipse with Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I test tomcat v8 in Eclipse Mars version. I create a Dynamic Web Project, and create a servlet. However, when I visit HelloWorld servlet, the web page is Error 404. Please how fix it

[image]

HelloWorld Servlet

```
package com.test.servlets;

/**
* Servlet implementation class HelloWorld
*/
@WebServlet("/HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public HelloWorld() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter printWriter  = response.getWriter();
    printWriter.println("<h1>Hello Friends!</h1>");
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

}
```

Comment: Could you try clean and build ? and also check URL correctly

Comment: my URL: localhost:8080/TomcatTest/HelloWorld

Comment: check this link http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html#undefined. In this link check out this line Copy the ROOT (Default) Web App into Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, narrow down the problem.

Has the app started correctly? Is it deployed at context path /TomcatTest? You can check both of these things by using Tomcat's Manager UI. To access the Manager UI you must first enable it: expand the Tomcat 8 Server node in Eclipse and look for the file /conf/tomcat-users.xml. Add the following line:

```
<user username="tomcat" password="password" roles="standard,manager-script, manager-ui" />
```

See the following for more info:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access

Restart the server and hit the following:

http://localhost:808/manager/html

You should see you app listed as running. If it is listed but not running you will then need to look at Tomcat's log files to see what has prevented the app from starting.

If the application is listed and is running. Check that you can hit http://localhost:8080/TomcatTest/index.jsp. If so, then application is deployed correctly and problem would appear to lie with the servlet mapping.